# How to remove scrollbars from IFrame?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to show the content of techcrunch in IFrame. I am using height:100% for IFrame, even then it shows the scrollbar. So ultimately there are two scrollbars one for the page and one for the IFrame.

http://jsbin.com/iboma4

I just want to have one scrollbar and that is for the page. I would like to grow my Iframe automatically so that it will not have any scrollbar.

Is it possible ?

Comment: The problem you'll have is that the iFrame won't grow beyond the current window size just because the page inside the iFrame is tall.  Removing the scrollbar will just stop viewers from being able to see anything past what fits in the window initially.  You could set the iFrame height to a high number, but that might not be what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid I think this is not possible: You would have to get the inlying document's height to adjust the `iframe` - something the Same Origin Policy will prevent you from doing.

Answer (score 5):

Add `scrolling="no"` to the `<iframe>`, like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.techcrunch.com" id="_content" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

[You can try it out here](http://jsbin.com/iboma4/2)

Comment: It is of no use. You can't see the complete content of techcrunch even if you use your mouse scroll wheel.

Answer (score 0):

`seamless="seamless"` for HTML5 mode

As was found on http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/hide_scrollbar.cfm

Comment: `seamless="seamless"` is not supported by any major browsers. [Source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-seamless)